# A Hamiltonian cycles (plural) problem?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, hamiltonian-path, network

I'll be brief. I have a set of n vertices in a complete weighted graph, some of these vertices can be thought of as power plants and the rest as cities, and I need to find the shortest way to connect every city to a powerplant such that every vertex has degree 2; which will give some union of disjoint cycles, each including one or more power pants.
This looks like a Hamiltonian cycle problem, except for the fact that I am allowed to use  several components.
This could be solved by considering every possible grouping of vertices and finding the Ham-cycle for each, but the Ham-cycle problem is already NP-hard, and the number of groupings is some function of n!, so its possible that the universe may end before I finish trying that.
Does anyone know what this problem is called (if it has a proper name), or any papers or references I might be able to use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a "Steiner" variant of the [cycle cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover).  You can solve it via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether edge $(i,j)$ appears among the cycles, with cost $c_{ij}$.  Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether node $i$ appears among the cycles.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} x_{ij}$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j): \text{$j$ is a power plant}} x_{ij} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all cities $i$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_{(i,j): k \in \{i,j\}} x_{ij} &= 2 y_k &&\text{for all $k$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each city to at least one power plant.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the degree-$2$ restriction.

Comment: "vertex cycle cover problem" that's what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: But vertex cycle cover covers every vertex, whereas you need to cover only the cities.  Also, vertex cycle cover does not force each city to be adjacent to a power plant.